# SubQuery working I want to add the rows not returned in the subquery

Tags: sql

This query works but I want to present as well the rows that are not chosen in the subquery. Here I get about 32 rows I want the others.

```
select wv1.worker_role, wv1.event_name from event_worker_role_view wv1 where wv1.worker_role in('A31 Servicer')
 
 and wv1.event_name in (select wv2.event_name from event_worker_role_view wv2  where
wv2.worker_role = 'A29i Clinician')
```

---

```
results of above query sample:
A31 Service     Agency Placement
A31 Service     Benefit Assignment
A31 Service     Clinical Summary
A31 Service     COVID Vaccination Card
```

results of full data: without the subquery. You can see here "Agency Placement" is in both roles. The others on the below list are not. I would like these others to display in the query with the subquery like Agency Placement for example.

```
A31 Service     Admission Note
A31 Service     Admission Utilization Review/Screening Note
A29i Licensed   Agency Placement
A31 Service     Agency Placement
A31 Service     Alcohol and/or Drug Screening
```

Comment: Show us some sample data

Comment: I don't understand, your query explicitly asks for the rows where worker_role in ('A31 Service') but you want rows with a different worker_role?

Comment: yes i want to know which event_name are rows with both of the worker_role types. the query lists those in both but i want to show the ones that are not in both as well.